# Waiting for an HTTP call to return a result from a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function inside a factory IsLoggedIn and i want it to use the result from it.

```
factory.IsLoggedIn = function () {
    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    LoginFactory.get({token: token },
    funtion(data){
          return true;
    },funtion(data){
          return false;
    }))
 }
```

in my controller

```
if(factory.IsLoggedIn())
{
       //Do something
}
```

this does not obviously works as  factory.IsLoggedIn() return a value before the http return the promises. Is there a way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
factory.IsLoggedIn = function () {
    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    return LoginFactory.get({token: token },
    funtion(data){
          return true;
    },funtion(data){
          return false;
    }))
 }
```

And then on the factory:

```
factory.IsLoggedIn().then(function(isLogged){
 if (isLogged) {
  // Do Something
 }
});
```

The explanation is the following. You need to *return* the **promise** so you can use the promise on the controller or wherever you want.